# Count distinct records in same table for given date range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by

I have a semi-working version of this already, see SQL Fiddle below:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/74ab3/3

The method I'm using works, for the most part, but requires me to build and populate a separate date table that I use to join back to my original table.  In addition, the way that I'm currently using it, once it matches records dates

What I am looking for is to be able to get a distinct `COUNT` of `custid` for each `groupid, cust_type, cust_date` combination that already exists.  The count should include a date range of itself and 3 months (`cust_date` and `dateadd(m, 2, cust_date)`).  For example, in January 2014, it should include in the distinct `COUNT` records from January 2014, February 2014 and March 2014.

I'm hoping to find a way to do this that won't require pre-population of a separate table.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/74ab3/50)

```
;WITH monthrange AS
(
  SELECT 0 as mnth UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2
), recordrange AS 
(
  SELECT groupid,custid,cust_type,DATEADD(month,-mnth,cust_date) cust_date
  FROM records cross join monthrange
)
SELECT DISTINCT d.groupid, d.cust_type, d.cust_date, COUNT(DISTINCT d.custid) as cust_count
FROM recordrange d
WHERE d.cust_date >= (SELECT MIN(cust_date) FROM records)
GROUP BY d.groupid, d.cust_type, d.cust_date
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not correct.  It produces too many results.  There should only be 12 rows, 1 for each record in the the "records" table.

Comment: @user2162331 - In your fiddle, for groupid 'FL444', there are only records for `01/01/2014`, `03/01/2014` and `07/01/2014`. In your output, you have rows for `02/01/2014`, `05/01/2014` and `06/01/2014` as well for this groupid. Can you edit your question and detail out the expected output.

Comment: @user2162331 - updated the answer to match the expected output and number of rows (14) as in your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
with dat as (
  select 1 line
       , cast('2014-01-01' as date) date_min
       , cast('2014-03-01' as date) date_max
  union all 
  select line + 1
       , dateadd(month,1,date_min)
       , dateadd(month,1,date_max) 
  from dat where line<12
)
select d.groupid, d.cust_type, dt.date_min, dt.date_max
     , count(distinct custid) as cust_count
from records d 
join dat dt on d.cust_date between dt.date_min and dt.date_max
group by d.groupid, d.cust_type, dt.date_min, dt.date_max;
```